# Plesk – PHP read and write to ‘root’ directory – permission

Tags: permissions, root, plesk, read-write

Current dedicated server Plesk (10.3) server setup as follow:

I have **MainDomain** setup to work in `httpdocs` (like public html) folder. Then I have **two domains** that are setup inside this folder, see structure below.

All sites works fine, but the problem occurs, when **domain1** or **domain2** want to read/write to folder that is in  `httpdocs` in this case **Test**.

```
--- MainDomain
    -- Httpdocs
       -- Some files
       --  Test
       -- Domain1
        -- Some files
       -- Domain2
        -- Some files
```

Don’t know the exact issues, but I did set the owner and group permission to root, but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an open_basedir restriction which comes from apache config:

php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/MainDomain/Domain1/:/tmp/"

So, if you want to access to /var/www/vhosts/MainDomain/httpdocs/ you have to add this path to open_basedir for Domain1 and Domain2 (I'm not sure but in 10.4 there is able to do it from Plesk GUI)

But actually, it's totally wrong because it's a real security threat.

Comment: Can you expand on security threat?

Comment: If one of child web sites will be compromised, all of web sites created under /var/www/vhosts/MainDomain/ will be compromised too, because there is no open_basedir restriction and files of this websites belong to one system user.